# PHP file triggers on every page load?

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, php

I've got a WordPress website that has a script which seems to be triggering every time any user loads a page. This PHP script is very simple (less than 25 lines) and is meant to be an API endpoint, so it shouldn't execute at all unless someone specifically navigates to it.

The script (which we will call **getLeaderboardUsers.php** for the purpose of this question) is located inside my website's `root directory` > `public_html` > `contract_projects` > `name_of_project`. My website is on a shared hosting server, but as far as I know everything is pretty standard default configurations.

When I do a full search (using [scandal](https://github.com/atom/scandal)) of every file in my website, the ***only*** place that references this file ever is my `.htaccess` file, which has the following lines:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /getLeaderboardUsers.php$/">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "private"
</IfModule>
</If>
```

Considering this is the only place that is referencing the file at all, I assume this must be the culprit? However, I don't understand how this snippit would be causing the `getLeaderboardUsers.php` script to *execute* on every page load of the website? `getLeaderboardUsers.php` is only used in a regex comparison there as far as I can tell?

#### Can anyone help me understand why this script is executing (potentially multiple times) on every page load? Thanks!

P.S. if any more information or clarity is needed to make this question more specific, then PLEASE let me know! I've tried looking through every resource I can find on .htaccess and doing as much digging as I possibly can on my own before posting this question.

Comment: For clarification: This script is showing up in my metrics as triggering dozens of times an hour with just one user (me) accessing the website, far more than any other script I have on the site. So I am _assuming_ this means it is triggering on every page load. I suppose it could be some other page load that is somehow causing the dozens of executions, but I never navigate to `getLeaderboardUsers.php` directly in my testing.

Comment: "I am assuming this means it is triggering on every page load" - Does it correspond to a page request? Although you you also suggest it could be called "multiple times on every page load". What "metrics" are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I am testing the website by blocking all outside traffic to it except my own: `order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from [my_ip]`.
  When I don't load any new pages, no CPU Seconds are recorded as being used by my site host. When I navigate to just a few pages (I just picked three random, front-facing pages. None of them were `getLeaderboardUsers.php`.) then the CPU Second usage shoots way up. According to my site host, they "presume that the issue with the high CPU seconds usage is caused by getLeaderboardUsers.php."

Comment: My site host claimed this because they said that `getLeaderboardUsers.php` is "the second most executed script" on my website outside of `index.php`. It garnered 38 executions after I navigated to three pages on my website.

Comment: If you remove the line from .htaccess, does it continue to happen?  If so, it must be being referenced somewhere else.  Are you using grep to do the search?  That will search what is actually on the server and not what you might think is there.  And don't forget grep is case sensitive.

Comment: Your server logs should indicate what request(s) are executing your script. As Steve suggests, you could remove any .htaccess, and also disable plugins to further narrow it down.

Comment: Are you including this file in any pages in your wordpress site?  (eg, does your theme or settings or config have an include or require directive that calls it?)  Does getLeaderboardUsers.php appear in your log files?

Comment: Sorry for the tardy replies here, everyone. My site host does not allow me to access the stats on most executed scripts myself, so it is annoying, slow, back-and-forth with them any time I want to ping those statistics.

Anyway, to answer @Steve 's questions, if I comment out all lines from `getLeaderboardUsers.php` completely, the executions stop. (No surprise.) I have commented out the lines found in the `.htaccess` file that I posted in the question and am waiting on a response from my web host. I will report back here with my findings.

Comment: @Steve For the search, I am using my text editor, Atom, which uses the Node module "[scandal](https://github.com/atom/scandal)". I'll update the question with the info.